# Upgrade Kibana 3 to Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I'm currently using Kibana 3 on ubuntu, and would like to upgrade to Kibana 4. However, I would like to keep my dashboard in Kibana 4 configured.
What I should know before upgrading Kibana3 to Kibana4 ?
Dashboards ? elastic search ? and so on..
Is it worth to do the upgrade?
Would love to hear some tips !
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboards can not be migrated from kibana3 to kibana4.  They must be rebuilt.

Kibana4 has a cleaner architecture (e.g. each panel defines the index against which it runs, etc), but it's missing some features that kibana3 and, of course, introduces some bugs of its own.

That said, you can't even download kibana3 any longer, so upgrading is the "right thing".

Comment: when you say `....each panel defines the index....` you mean each visualization, right? I started using Kibana from version 4.x so just making sure since what I know of is that there are no panels any more on the dashboard. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.